# Error message: Provided module can't be loaded. Cannot find module 'nodemailer'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

i have a firebase project on react framework, where i want to create firebase funcion that will send an email with nodemailer, but when i try to deploy it, it says that nodemailer is missing

ive tried:

checking dependencies in packages.json,
its version,
if its downloaded with `npm install nodemailer --save`,

nodemailer is imported like this:

`import * as nodemailer from 'nodemailer';`

when deploying, is gives error:

```
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Provided module can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'nodemailer'
Require stack:
- /workspace/lib/index.js
- /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/loader.js
- /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/main.js`your text`
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/lib/index.js:6:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.9.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

firebase.json :

```
 "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
      ]
    }
  ],
```

...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Is your `package.json` file in your configured functions directory? Can you post the scrubbed versions of your `firebase.json` and `package.json` files?

Comment: Hi, if i understand it right, the package.json is in configured functions directory, i also posted firebase.json and package.json files

Comment: Your `package.json` file doesn't have an entry for "nodemailer". You should rerun the `npm i --save nodemailer` in your functions directory. Alternatively, you can just add `"nodemailer": "^6.9.7"` to your dependencies array.

Comment: Yes, that worked, added it manually, then had to run npm install in functions so package.json and package-lock.json are synchronized and function was deployed successfully. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at your error message:

```
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code.
Error message: Provided module can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'nodemailer'
```

When you see this error message, you should:

1. Check the location of the `package.json` file. You want to make sure that it is located inside your configured functions directory (normally this is $projectDir/functions - this value is set inside your `firebase.json` file in the project directory as `"source": "<foldername>"` in the `functions` object).
2. Check the `dependencies` array inside the `package.json` file. This array should name each module used by your code and the suitable versions to be installed. At the time of writing, the entry for `nodemailer` should look like `"nodemailer": "^6.9.7"`.
3. Check the `devDependencies` array inside the `package.json` file and remove/move any entries that should be installed with your deployed function to `dependencies`.
4. Redeploy and check for further errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and what helped me is: Removing the nodemailer with npm uninstall, removing all the nodemailer instances from package.json and package-lock.json, and then making sure to install nodemailer when you are inside the "functions" folder and not in your project folder.. because after installing firebase functions you have now another package.json inside the functions folder and that is the one that needs to have the nodemailer.